# how to overcome bottomnavigationbar overlaps in flutter

Tags: flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm new to Android Flutter, I want to ask about using the bottomnavigationbar, I have 2 pages, each of which has a different bottomnavigationbar, I try to call the second page from one of the items, the output overlaps, my question:

1. How to call a new page by selecting one of the bottom navigationbar items, so i can call another new page
2. How to ensure that the botomnavigationbar's second page display doesn't overlap with the previous page.[my script for page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPxOd.jpg)[The output for script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMujK.jpg)[script for call page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmUDp.jpg)[script fot page 2 (same with script for page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGDGb.jpg)[The output output oberlaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StxSK.jpg)
3. how to call a new page by clicking the bottom navigationbar item.
4. How to deal with overlapping bottom navigationbar